# How to prove that UMVUE does not exist for non-constant function?

Tags: statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

This is problem 1.9 of chapter 2 from Lehmann and Casella:

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a sample (assuming i.i.d.) from a discrete distribution which assigns probability $1/3$ to each of the points $\theta-1, \theta, \theta+1$. $\theta$ ranges over all integers. Prove that no non-constant function of $\theta$ has a UMVUE.

My approach: Assume the simplest case $n=1$. We can use the relationship between UMVUE and unbiased estimator of zero to tackle this issue.

Suppose $T(x)$ is a UMVUE for $g(\theta)$ for some function $g$. Then for an unbiased estimator of zero $U(x)$, we have
$$
E_\theta U = 1/3(U(\theta-1) + U(\theta) + U(\theta+1)) = 0, \ \forall \theta \in \mathbb{Z},
$$
i.e.,
$$
U(\theta-1) + U(\theta) + U(\theta+1) = 0, \ \forall \theta \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Then we have
$$
U(\theta-1) = U(\theta + 2), \ \forall \theta \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Now we use the fact that if $T$ is UMVUE, then for any $U$ that is an unbiased estimator of zero, we have
$$
E_\theta[TU] = 0.
$$
This implies that $TU$ is also an unbiased estimator of zero. Hence, for any unbiased estimator of zero $U$:
$$
T(\theta-1)U(\theta-1) = T(\theta + 2)U(\theta+2), \ \forall \theta \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
This means that
$$
T(\theta-1) = T(\theta+2), \ \forall \theta \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
This gives us
$$
1/3(T(\theta-1) + T(\theta) + T(\theta+1)) = 1/3(T(\theta) + T(\theta+1) + T(\theta+2)), \ \forall \theta \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
Now the RHS is $g(\theta)$ while the LHS is $g(\theta+1)$. Therefore,
$$
g(\theta) = g(\theta + 1), \ \forall \theta \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$
This shows that $g$ is a constant function of $\theta$. That is, UMVUE does not exist for non-constant function of $\theta$.

Now the part I am stuck at is how do I prove this for $n > 1$? I don't see an immediate induction-type argument or something else and carrying out direct derivation through brute force seems extremely complicated.

Any hint would be helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: If UMVUE exists for a non-constant function, that UMVUE must be a function of a complete sufficient statistic. So if you can argue that a complete sufficient statistic does not exist in this model then that may help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I have been thinking about this for a couple days. From what you said, it reminds me of Lehmann-Scheffe theorem. However, Lehmann-Scheffe thm states that if there is a function of the complete sufficient statistics which is also an unbiased estimator, then it is UMVUE. It seems if what you said is true, then shouldn't Lehmann-Scheffe thm include a if and only if statement? Can you possibly clarify this point? Also, it would be appreciated if you can point me to some source about what you stated. Thank you!

Comment: What I said is not true in general, but I thought this kind of argument might work for this problem.

Comment: Actually, I have figured out a solution that does not require complete and sufficient statistics. It only uses the fact that UMVUE and unbiased estimator of zero are uncorrelated. I will put up an answer later.